# Generating a Change Log from Subversion Logs and integrating with Jira

Tags: svn, logging, jira

We use Subversion for version control and Jira for tickets. All our commit messages have a Jira ticket id in it. The repository has a traditional organization with a main trunk and a version branch.

I'd like to answer this question:

> Which *closed* ticket items entered in this release?

See that there are some caveats, like when an item is committed in a release branch and in the main trunk.

Is there a tool that already does it for me? Or should I write my own Subversion log analyzer tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll either have to write you own log analyzer for that or use the svn hooks to post them to a system as they get committed.

There is also a jira plugin that supports some of what you are asking for:

https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/SVN/Subversion+JIRA+plugin